# SQL joining tables including NULL counts

Tags: sql, join

This I'm hoping is an easy fix, I have 2 tables, one of days over a 6 month period, the other with sitenames, day(date) and count of attendances that day.

I'm wanting to create a table where for each site, it has a row for every day in the 6 month period and takes that sites count which corresponds to the day, but I also want it to show where there is a NULL (no attendance on that day) - I can do it where it brings out only days with attendance but not the other way around. :(

Example data here: NOTE, the data is held in two temporary tables

Date table #Data

```
CallDate    rn
2022-08-01  1
2022-08-02  2
2022-08-03  3
2022-08-04  4
2022-08-05  5
2022-08-06  6
2022-08-07  7
2022-08-08  8
```

Attendance table: #SiteData

```
SiteName    CallDate    Count
Bassetlaw   2022-08-30    1
Bassetlaw   2022-08-31    1
Bassetlaw   2022-09-13    3
Bassetlaw   2022-09-15    5
Bassetlaw   2022-09-23    1
Bassetlaw   2022-09-27    1
Bassetlaw   2022-11-21    1
Bassetlaw   2022-11-23    1
Bassetlaw   2022-11-26    1
Bassetlaw   2022-11-28    1
```

So in this instance, I would have 6 months worth of rows, but only 10 days worth of data. I need NULLs for the other days, not just 8 rows.

NOTE: There are more sites, I would want this repeated for all site. In essence, I want a table that has all sites with a row per site per day for 6 months irrespective if they had an attendance or not.

Comment: what DBMS are you using? Also, this would probably far easier in your data layer rather than doing it in the db itself

Comment: This sounds super easy and should be done with a LEFT JOIN command. One more question though: The table SiteData looks like it has only one entry per date. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is done by using the `LEFT JOIN` command.

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0218c/2

```
CREATE TABLE T_Data (
  rn int,
  CallDate date
);

CREATE TABLE T_SiteData (
  CallDate date,
  Amount int
);

INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 1, '2022-08-01';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 2, '2022-08-02';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 3, '2022-08-03';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 4, '2022-08-04';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 5, '2022-08-05';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 6, '2022-08-06';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 7, '2022-08-07';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 8, '2022-08-08';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 10, '2022-08-09';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 11, '2022-08-10';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 12, '2022-08-11';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 13, '2022-08-12';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 14, '2022-08-13';
INSERT INTO T_Data SELECT 15, '2022-08-14';

INSERT INTO T_SiteData SELECT '2022-08-01', 1;
INSERT INTO T_SiteData SELECT '2022-08-03', 1;
INSERT INTO T_SiteData SELECT '2022-08-05', 3;
INSERT INTO T_SiteData SELECT '2022-08-12', 5;

SELECT
  d.*,
  sd.Amount AS [Count]
FROM
  T_Data AS d
LEFT JOIN
  T_SiteData AS sd
ON
  sd.CallDate = d.CallDate
```

This returns the following:

```
rn  CallDate    Count
1   2022-08-01  1
2   2022-08-02  (null)
3   2022-08-03  1
4   2022-08-04  (null)
5   2022-08-05  3
6   2022-08-06  (null)
7   2022-08-07  (null)
8   2022-08-08  (null)
10  2022-08-09  (null)
11  2022-08-10  (null)
12  2022-08-11  (null)
13  2022-08-12  5
14  2022-08-13  (null)
15  2022-08-14  (null)
```

I used the MS SQL server syntax. But the `SELECT` query should be the same on almost any other DBMS.

If the table SiteData contains more than one entry per `CallDate`, the query needs to be adjusted. But your example only showed one entry per `CallDate`.